# jQuery DataTable() function crashes the table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the info loaded in table by `$("#mytable").DataTable().data().`
but it crashes my table. It takes the result from the first page and recreates the table so that I have only first 50 results(that is the default result) with new table and pagination (wrapper).

jQuery: 1.11.3

Update: 
using DataTable() not tableData() sorry for mistake

Comment: can you post some code? that would be really helpful, it may not be the data that's causing the issue.

Comment: @pegla which part ?  html ? js ?

Comment: well everything put it on a fiddle or something.

Comment: Lyslexia problem! Try `.DataTable()` instead of `.tableData()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a sulution to this If somebody alse has this question.

`DataTable()` has an option `"retrieve"`, so if it is true, `DataTable()` will return the new created table object. I save that and use whenever I need it.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  "retrieve": true
});
```

Something like this. Not an elegant solution, but works fine.